# Windows Boot Manager complains UNetbootin has some files missing

Tags: dual-boot, unetbootin

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 and installed it on my system using UNetbootin. When everything is finished and I restarted, and selected UNetbootin. Don't know why but Windows Boot Manager complains that some necessary file are not present or corrupt. Please send me the details you require and the possible reason.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File:  

  Status: 0xc700000b  

  Info:
```

Note:

1. I want to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
2. I am absolute beginner to Linux.

Comment: `Status: 0xc700000b` is an error code that Windows shows when a required file is missing. If there is anything at all on the same line after where it says `File:` that information would be very helpful in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use another tool in Windows in order to create a USB boot drive with Ubuntu.

- A cloning tool, that clones the iso file to a USB pendrive:

  [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)
- An extracting tool, that extracts the content from the iso file and rearranges it when written to a USB pendrive:

  [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie)

  (Unetbootin is an extracting tool)
- See the following link, if you want more detailed information,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)